# Shelf life of whey protein?

Tags: nutrition, protein

I am looking to purchase some of [this whey protein](http://www.cnpprofessional.co.uk/whey-protein-2-25kg.html/).

My diet is fairly high protein anyway, and I plan to consume two portions of the powder on lifting days, which are roughly every other day (with the odd bonus rest/football day).

I assume that as it is a dry powder, then the 3 months I project this tub will last will be fine, but I just wanted to check.

Comment: I don't know about UK laws, but US food law requires an expiration date on the container. It is a dry powder, but there are small amounts of fat still in the mix, which could go rancid. Three months is probably well within the acceptable range, ~ 2 years is shelf life IIRC. One question, why only take it on lifting days? You should be planning a daily diet, rather than "spiking" on certain days.

Comment: From what I have read, I only really need it to aid recovery, as I get a lot of protein anyway.

Comment: I haven't had any problems taking it right w/in a couple months of the expiration date, which was a couple years after I bought it. Helps when I fall off of working out, then get back into it and check the expiration date --- SWEET! ANOTHER YEAR BEFORE IT EXPIRES!

Answer (score 2):

If it's not exposed to heat or light, protein powder will last pretty much forever. 3 months is no problem. Just keep it in the airtight, opaque container it comes in.